# How to chain curl such that the output of one become another's input?

Tags: linux, curl, continuous-integration

Could someone tell me how to pass the output of one CURL GET to another CURL POST? I mean something like this:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data "{\"specification\": curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request GET "https://user:pass@anotherhost"}" "https://user:pass@localhost"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `jq` to craft JSON in the shell.

```
response="$(curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request GET "https://user:pass@anotherhost")"
data="$(jq "{specification: .}" <<< "$response")"
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data "$data" "https://user:pass@localhost"
```

Keep in mind, that passwords in command line arguments are public to the host.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to use command substitution. The result would be something like this.

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request POST --data "{\"specification\": $(curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" --request GET "https://user:pass@anotherhost")}" "https://user:pass@localhost"
```

$() is used for command substitution and it invokes a subshell. The command in the parentheses (a.k.a. round brackets) of $() is executed in a subshell and the output is then placed in the original command.

So the curl GET will be executed in a subshell and the result will be passed to the curl POST

You can read more about it at the link below:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html